# Reordering bars in ggplot after pivot_longer

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to figure out how to manually control the order in which the bars in this plot show up. I am essentially using `pivot_longer()` to include roughly 7 different variables all on the same plot, and I'd love a way to manually control the order in which those plots are displayed. I am also grouping and using dodge to have the bars next to each other instead of stacked. Thanks!

I'd also like to be able to manually re-name each variable as its displayed along the x axis as well.

```
d %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('var')) %>% 
  group_by(gender, name) %>% 
  summarize(percent = mean(value == 1)) %>% 
  ggplot() + aes(name, percent, fill = gender) + 
  geom_col(position = "dodge", color = "black") +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
        legend.position = c(0.9, 0.9)) +
  coord_flip()
```

```
structure(list(gender = structure(c("Male", "Male", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male"), label = "Q4", format.stata = "%24s"), 
    var1 = structure(c("0", "0", "1", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
    "0", "0"), format.stata = "%9s"), var2 = structure(c("0", 
    "1", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), format.stata = "%9s"), 
    var3 = structure(c("0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
    "0", "0"), format.stata = "%9s"), var4 = structure(c("1", 
    "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "1", "1", "0", "0"), format.stata = "%9s"), 
    var5 = structure(c("1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", 
    "0", "0"), format.stata = "%9s")), row.names = c(NA, -10L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Hello todd_b. It would be useful to add a minimum reproducible example of your data.

Comment: Sure thing, just added some data.

Comment: OP, your example is not working for me as is.  Can you please adjust to make this reproducible?

Comment: @chemdork123 I'm not sure what to adjust--I just tried it again and it works fine for me, and the ggplot produces a barplot.

Answer (score 2):

A way to define your "individual" categories is to define the levels of a factor.
{ggplot} uses this order.

I am not a big fan of doing this manipulation in the ggplot() or geom_xxxx() calls, thus I suggest you slot in a mutate to perform the sequencing.

Try:

```
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('var')) %>% 
  group_by(gender, name) %>% 
  summarize(percent = mean(value == 1)) %>% 
#--------------------- create a factor with your preferred sequence --------------  
  mutate(name = factor(name, levels = c("var5","var3","var4","var2","var1"))) %>%
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
  ggplot() + aes(name, percent, fill = gender) + 
  geom_col(position = "dodge", color = "black") +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
        legend.position = c(0.9, 0.9)) +
  coord_flip()
```

Note: if you define your x and y mapping respectively, you can avoid coord_flip(). geom_col() recognises aes(x = percent, y = name).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add a solution I figured out for the ordering and labeling that I think is much easier than dealing with factors (as suggested above):

```
order1 <- c("var1", "var4", "var3", "var2", "var5")
label1 <- c("Health", "Anxious", "Worry", "Happy", "Uncertain")
```

Just add `+ scale_x_discrete(limits = order1)` to the end of whatever plot you're trying to make.

And then for labels, you can do the same thing with `+ scale_x_discrete(labels= label1)`

Comment: well done. This would be the ggplot() scale equivalent to defining a "factor" (discrete steps and setting the labels).